# replicating borders in 2d numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to replicate the border of a 2d numpy array:

```
>>> from numpy import *
>>> test = array(range(9)).reshape(3,3)
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

Is there an easy way to replicate a border in any direction?

for example:

```
>>>> replicate(test, idx=0, axis=0, n=3) 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

**edit**:

the following function did the job:

```
def replicate(a, xy, se, n):
    rptIdx = numpy.ones(a.shape[0 if xy == 'X' else 1], dtype=int)
    rptIdx[0 if se == 'start' else -1] = n + 1
    return numpy.repeat(a, rptIdx, axis=0 if xy == 'X' else 1)
```

with xy in ['X', 'Y'] and se in ['start', 'end']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.repeat`:

```
In [5]: np.repeat(test, [4, 1, 1], axis=0)
Out[5]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

But for larger/variable arrays it will be more difficult to define the repeats argument (`[4, 1, 1]`, which is in this case how many times you want to repeat each row).

Comment: thank you. I think I can use with `ones_like` and `repeat` to get what I want.